# How to install qgis WMTS client in windows

Tags: wmts

I want to get QGIS WMTS client installed in windows? I need to know the steps. I also want source code if possible in C/C++.

Answer (score 2):

The WMTS client is installed by default, see [QGIS as OGC Data Client](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/ca/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/ogc_client_support.html).

If you want the codes, go to [GitHub:QGIS](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS) and [search for WMTS](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=wmts)